# Problems in importing modules in flask app

Tags: flask, python-import

[image]

I am having lot of problem in importing modules.
The content in my files is above:

run.py:

```
from erp import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

all_blueprints.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

from blueprint_finance.all_resources import api_finance

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:////tmp/test.db"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)

app.register_blueprint(api_finance)
```

erp/**init**.py

```
from .all_blueprints import app, db, ma
```

database1.py

```
from erp import app

class Author(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
```

I keep getting import errors, the current one is

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/arsalan/python_practise/MY_WORK_FILES/React_works/React_Container_Mount/backend/run.py", line 25, in 
>       from erp import app
>     File "/home/arsalan/python_practise/MY_WORK_FILES/React_works/React_Container_Mount/backend/erp/**init**.py", line 1, in 
>       from .all_blueprints import app, db, ma
>     File "/home/arsalan/python_practise/MY_WORK_FILES/React_works/React_Container_Mount/backend/erp/all_blueprints.py", line 12, in 
>       from blueprint_finance.all_resources import api_finance
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'blueprint_finance'

If anyone can point out the mistake's' that will be great favor because I am lost since yesterday. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way you create your blueprints is not the right way ([See this link for a detailed explanation](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xv-a-better-application-structure)).

If we refer to the way you have structured your code,

```
erp/
    blueprint_finance     ---> is your blueprint package
        __init__.py       ---> is where you create your blueprint
    all_blueprints.py     ---> is where you register your blueprint
```

let's start with the `erp/blueprint_finance/__init__.py` file:

```
from flask import Blueprint

bp = Blueprint('blueprint_finance', __name__)

from erp.blueprint_finance import all_resources
from erp.blueprint_finance.finances_resources import resource1
```

`erp/all_blueprints.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:////tmp/test.db"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)

from erp.blueprint_finance import bp as blueprint_finance_bp
app.register_blueprint(blueprint_finance_bp)
```